# Jetty log http header

Tags: web-services, rest, logging, http-headers, jetty

I log the http request on server, but I don't have the HTTP Header.

How can I log the HTTP Header on server?

I do this : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback

My jetty's version is 8.1.3.

Thanks

Vince